# How to set client-based ACL on iscsi target?

Tags: linux, redhat, iscsi

Say I have the following set up.

```
<target iqn.2012-02.local.mydomain.server1.target1>
    backing-store /dev/virtstore/virtimage1
</target>

<target iqn.2012-02.local.mydomain.server2.target2>
    backing-store /dev/virtstore/virtimage2
</target>
```

If I'm on server1, I can see both targets. How can I make it so that if I scan the target, only one `target` shows up (the `iqn.2012-02.local.mydomain.server1.target1`).

edit: targets and initiators are red hat linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LUN masking. Your target should have a feature that lets you choose a list of devices that will be able to access it.

Comment: If I'm using the tools that come with Redhat, how would I go about doing that? normally I would do that on the SAN or fibre level but I'm a newbie with iscsi.

Comment: Oh, I assumed this was to some sort of storage device. If you're providing iscsi disks through linux, I can't help you. Sorry.